# How to remove special characters from a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a string like this

```
{
    "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK
Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK
Add Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK
Connecting to Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Connected:OK
Disconnecting from Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Disconnected:OK
Delete Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK
\"": ""
}
```

How can I remove special characters and obtain the output like shown below, using jQuery:

```
test:Connect_Disconnect,os:Windows NT,report:Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK
Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK
Add Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK
Connecting to Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Connected:OK
Disconnecting from Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Disconnected:OK
Delete Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK
```

Comment: Explicitly, what precise characters do you wish to remove?

Comment: You mean JSON string? Well it's not valid JSON.

Comment: I think the Questioner wishes to remove the "\" character

Comment: i want to remove only "" and / charecters

Comment: @Sush whats your actual output??

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var product= $("#product").val().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ')
```

Comment: i want to remove only ""  and / charecters

Answer (score 0):

Please try replace function in javascript

```
  var val='"\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Add Profile to the Client:OK Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK Connecting to Access Point:OK Verify the State is Connected:OK Disconnecting from Access Point:OK Verify the State is Disconnected:OK Delete Profile to the Client:OK Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK \"": ""';

        val=val.replace(/"/g,'');
        val=val.replace(/\\/g,'');
```

Comment: it is the output when i tried ur code`{test\\:\\Connect_Disconnect\\,\\os\\:\\Windows NT\\,\\report\\:\\Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK
Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK
Add Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:OK
Connecting to Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Connected:OK
Disconnecting from Access Point:OK
Verify the State is Disconnected:OK
Delete Profile to the Client:OK
Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK
\\:}"`